# Angular, How to get classes by Jquery after getting data from server and *ngFor has been applied for them?

Tags: jquery, angular, ngfor, magnific-popup

I am using Jquery in Angular with typescript,
I want to get all the classes that have been generated by ngFor loop..
I am building a products site...
I am getting the products from node.JS Server...
after I get the Products, I am applying ngFor for them,
In this ngFor I am using a class name imagePopup,
when I run this code
let x = $('.imagePopup');
I get x.length = 0;
I'm not getting the classes from the ngFor loop..
How can I get all of them?

my Code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.productsSubjectSubscribe = this.localProductService.myProductsSubject.subscribe(x=> {
       this.myProducts = x;
       let y = $('.open-poup-image');
       console.log(y);
   });
}
```

console.log(y) gets length = 0

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myProducts;index as i" class="item" [id]="'item_'+item._id">
     <div class="item_img">
          <a class="open-poup-image"
            [href]="'src-to-image.jpg">Open
            image</a>
          <img
            [src]="src-to-image.jpg">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's very hard to pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: In Angular, to get a reference of a series of divs, a ViewChildren is used: see the docs:https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren. Well, the docs it's not very clear, you can use a templateReference variable ( a simple `#myelement` in the html tag and use `@ViewChildren('myelement') elements:QueryList<ElementRef>`)

Comment: I have edited the question and add some code...

Comment: I recommend looking for an alternative that doesn't use jQuery, such as https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/

Answer (score 0):

If I can give advice, don't use jQuery with Angular. It causes lots of problems :/
Show us your code, and we try to figure out, how can we solve it :)